# Who has the power to issue a witness summons?

Tags: united-kingdom, law

In the US, Congressional committees have the power to issue subpoenas, compelling a witness to testify before the given committee.

In the UK we have a witness summons, which can be issued in court.

But do any House of Commons committees have the power to issue a witness summons, compelling a witness to testify before the given committee (like in the US) ? If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Select Committees have the power to compel witnesses to attend. To quote from the [Disciplinary and Penal Powers of the House factsheet](https://www.parliament.uk/documents/commons-information-office/g06.pdf)

> A refusal by a witness to attend a Select Committee may be construed as a contempt. If a witness is unwilling to attend, the committee can agree to order the attendance of a witness at a specified date and time. Such an order is signed by the Chairman of the Committee and is either forwarded to the witness by registered post or served personally by a member of the Serjeant at Arms' office. Similarly, an order may be served upon a witness (not being a Minister, a Member of either House, or an officer of a Government department) for the production of papers or records required by a Select Committee.
>
> If a Select Committee has issued a summons to a witness to attend, or produce papers, and the witness has not responded, it is for the House to act (or not) on the basis of a Report made to it by the committee. The House may order the Serjeant at Arms as Warrant Officer of the House to serve a Warrant on the witness. Formerly, the Serjeant would be sent with the Mace as the symbol of his authority, to order the attendance of witnesses. However, by the end of the seventeenth century, it had become accepted that the Mace was required to remain in place for the House to meet. Therefore, the device of the Speaker's Warrant was invented. In serving the Warrant, the Serjeant or his appointee may call on the full assistance of the civil authorities, including the police.
>
> The last use of the Warrant to summon witnesses was in January 1992 (when the Maxwell brothers were reluctant to attend the Social Security Select Committee inquiry into the operation of pension funds).